# How do i get full capacity from Fusion drive on vmWare ESXi 6.0 Mac Mini 7,1

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, mac-mini, vmware, fusion-drive

I managed to install the free vmWare ESXi 6.0 hypervisor on a Mac Mini 7,1. It's running rather nicely from a USB memory.

The mini has a 2TB Fusion drive. My problem is that i can only get the 106 GB SSD drive to show for datastorage, not the remaining spinning platter capacity. Going to `Configuration -> Storage -> Add storage` will not discover any more disk (as won't connecting a USB3 HDD to the mac, but that doesn't quite surprise me).

What should i do to get all the disk capacity to use?

Comment: Did you check it even understands what Fusion is? Windows doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The ESXi 6.0.0 update 2 solves this problem. The Fusion disk is recognised as two separate disks (which they in fact are). With that, i now have two datastores, one on the SSD and another one on the HDD.

What i usually do is install the guests on small virtual disks on the SSD datastore and give them a larger chunk on the HDD datastore. I've also successfully used Linux LVM to extend partitions on the SSD to "continue" to the HDD, but that's for another StackExchange question.

Answer (score 0):

Install the custom VIB from [virtuallyGhetto.com](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2015/02/esxi-6-0-works-ootb-for-apple-mac-mini-mac-pro.html).